# How to expand the splitted window using short key?

Tags: split, tabbed-user-interface

I have two vertically splited windows.

[image]

I see from [Ctrl+W s not splitting windows in Vim](https://superuser.com/questions/342041/ctrlw-s-not-splitting-windows-in-vim) that `Ctrl-W-|` should resize the window. But it does not. Actually, nothing happens.

If I manually resize the window and then press `Ctrl-W-=`, then it splits window on two equal parts back.

[image]

`help CTRL-W` says:

```
CTRL-W_bar  CTRL-W |       set window width to N columns
```

I'm a bit confused because of `bar`. What does it mean?
And the question is, why `Ctrl-W-|` does not work and is there any other options?

Comment: Just downvote has no feedback and says me nothing. Plz leave some note here then.

Comment: @Quasímodo thank you for your feedback! i added extra description. Hope it makes a bit more sense what i mean.

Comment: It does, it is a legit question

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm a bit lost here... Note that `CTRL-W |` involves separate keystrokes. First press "w" while holding the Control key (that's the `CTRL-W` part), then *release* the control key and press `|` (which typically means holding the Shift key while pressing backslash, at least on an English/American QWERTY keyboard.) Is that the sequence that you're typing? This command `CTRL-W |` should maximize the width of the current window. That looks like what you have on your screenshot at the bottom. Is that *after* that keystroke? `CTRL-W =` should get you back to the one at the top.

Comment: And "bar" is how one would describe the `|` key or `|` symbol. It's a bar. The Vim help docs refer to it as "bar", mostly since the `|` character can be considered as a special character in some contexts, so it tries to use a textual description for indexing commands that include it...

Comment: @filbranden thank you! exactly, i just figured this out with Qausimodo couple minutes ago:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be pressing `Ctrl`, `W` and `|` all together. That is incorrect. You should do

- `Ctrl-W`,
- **release** both `Ctrl` and `W`,
- and only then hit `|`.

I was really surprised to see that pressing `Ctrl-W-=` all together worked on the other hand.

---

From comments, the problem was that you missed that the "bar" or "pipe" symbol `|` is entered by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> in your keyboard layout.

Comment: mvim is vim wrapper for mac. in a meanwhile i solved it. it works a bit differently. Ctrl + W, then Shift + \. Basically pipe - it's shift + \. Thank you for taking part!

Comment: `CTRL-W-=` without releasing the "Control" key will typically work because `CTRL-=` simply just produces a `=`. On the other hand, `CTRL-|` typically produces the same as `CTRL-\ `. You can see these easily in Vim in Insert mode, by typing them after a `CTRL-V` (which inserts the next symbol literally.) `CTRL-V CTRL-=` just inserts a `=`, while `CTRL-V CTRL-|` inserts a `^\ ` (that's how a `CTRL-\ ` is displayed.)